# jquery: when click, highlight the row

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I use `best_in_place`.

I try to highlight the row that the checkbox of this row was checked. but it doesn't work.

`application.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place();
});


$('.highlight_on_success').bind("ajax:success", function(){
   $(this).closest('tr').effect('highlight'));
});
```

and this is my `index.html.erb`:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>TODO TASKS</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Done</th>
    <th>Admin Email</th>
    <th>Task</th>
    <th>Done</th>
  </tr>

<% @tasks_worker_todo.each do |task| %>
  <tr>
    <td = "done_id"> <%= best_in_place task, :done,:classes => 'highlight_on_success', type:     :checkbox, collection: %w[No Yes] %></td>
    <td><%= task.admin_mail %></td>
    <td><%= task.task %></td>
    <td><%= task.done %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br><br>
<br><br>

<h1>DONE TASKS</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Done</th>
    <th>Admin Email</th>
    <th>Task</th>
    <th>Done</th>
  </tr>

<% @tasks_worker_done.each do |task| %>
  <tr>
    <td> <%= best_in_place task, :done, type: :checkbox, collection: %w[No Yes]%></td>
    <td><%= task.admin_mail %></td>
    <td><%= task.task %></td>
    <td><%= task.done %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />
</body>
</html>
```

please help!

**UPDATE:**

I tried the next lines but there is no light :/

```
$('.highlight_on_success').bind($("#done_id")).click(function(){ 
    $(this).closest('tr').effect('highlight'));‌​
});
```

this is how my html looks so:

[image]

the checkbox is above the green line (is changed from 'yes' to 'no').

(don't relate with the column above the red line)

Comment: In title you say 'bind click', but on code you are trying to bind to 'ajax:success'. Which is it that you wish to accomplish?

Comment: @bvukelic, I updated my title. I want that if the user checked the box, the row will be highlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've struggled last couple of hours and made it work , partialy ;)

Try to put this (coffeescript) in your file , for example `tasks.js.coffe`:

```
jQuery ->
  $('.best_in_place').best_in_place()

$(".highlight_on_success").bind "ajax:success", ->
  $(this).effect "highlight",
    color: "red",
    1000
```

I've said partialy , because there is no `closest("tr")` call , which I think is not fatal .

I've researched about the `ajax:success` , it is used in every input and controle (including checkbox) of best_in_place .

Here is what I have in my `show.html.haml` :

```
%tr
  %td
    = best_in_place @product, :task, :type => :checkbox, :collection => ["Yes", "NOpe"], :classes => 'highlight_on_success'
```

As you can see , defining the `id` is avoided , the gem has its own convention for naming inputs , so there is no possibility to change the `id` of the checkbox.

Comment: Now I am reallllly happy , sir.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you.. have a beautiful life! thank you! you are a good man!

Comment: Good luck with your application , thank you for the good words !

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$('.highlight_on_success').on('click',function(){ 
    $(this).closest('tr').effect('highlight');‌​
});
```

Comment: @thank you but it doesn't work :/ (there is no highlight when I press the checkbox)

Comment: Are you sure the checkbox has a `.highlight_on_success` class _before_ you click it? Or does it get that class only after you click it _and_ the AJAX call is finished?

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand you. I only did what I wrote: <td = "done_id"> <%= best_in_place task, :done,:classes => 'highlight_on_success', type: :checkbox, collection: %w[No Yes] %></td>

nothing else..

Comment: I want to highlight all the line that the checkedbox is found in.

Comment: @AlonShmiel Can you please copy in your question the HTML as it is rendered on page? Some of us don't use Ruby or best_in_place, but may still be able to help you with the JavaScript bits, you know.

Comment: I added it: index.html.erb.